# How to avoid duplicate records when inserting data to db using "async" library

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
const obj =[
        {userName:'a',firstName:'kote',lastName:'perumalla  '},
        {userName:'a',firstName:'kote',lastName:'perumalla  '},
        {userName:'as',firstName:'koteswararaO',lastName:'perumalla'},
        {userName:'as',firstName:'koteswararaoH',lastName:'perumalla'},
         ];
     async.each(obj,function(item,callback){
        MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
      const DaTa = db.db("mydb"); 
         const asa =item.userName;    DaTa.collection("Campus").find({userName:item.userName}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if(result.length <=0){
            DaTa.collection("Campus").insertMany(obj,function(err,result){ 
                if(result){
                  return   callback();
                }
                    })
                  }   
        else{
            DaTa.collection("Campus").updateOne({userName:item.userName},{$set:{"firstName":item.firstName}},function(er,result){
                console.log(result +'1 record is updated')
                if(result){
                   return  callback();
                }
                })
            }
        db.close();
        callback('Done');
            })
     });
     },function(err,result){
        console.log('completed')
     })
```

I am using `.each` method of `async` package in Nodejs. I want to avoid insertion of the duplicate records to the MongoDB database.

Please tell me what part of my code should be changed for achieving async insertion of unique records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var DaTa;
MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    DaTa = db.db("mydb");
    async.eachSeries(obj,function(item,callback){
        console.log("*****************************")
        const asa =item.userName;
        // DaTa.createIndex( { "_id": 1 }, { unique: true } );
        console.log("item: ",item)
        DaTa.collection("Campus").find({userName:item.userName}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            console.log(result.length)
            console.log("result: ", result)
            if(result.length <=0){
                console.log("doc not found")
                DaTa.collection("Campus").insert(item,function(err,result){

                    if(result){
                        callback();
                    }
                })
            }else{
                console.log("doc found")
                DaTa.collection("Campus").update({userName:item.userName},{$set:{"firstName":item.firstName}},function(er,result){
                    // console.log(result +'1 record is updated')
                    console.log("doc update result: ",result.result)
                    if(result) {
                        callback();
                    } 
                })
            }
        })
    }, function(err,result){
        console.log('############ completed ##################')
    })
  // db.close()
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a unique index in MongoDB.

```
db.collectionName.createIndex( { "userName": 1 }, { unique: true } );
```

Comment: async.each(obj,function(item,callback){

    MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
  // if (err) throw err;
  const DaTa = db.db("mydb");
  
     const asa =item.userName;
  DaTa.createIndex( { "userName": 1 }, { unique: true } );
    DaTa.collection("Campus").find({userName:item.userName}).toArray(function(err, result) {

Comment: Sir.... obj data is inserted in to database on the time if condition is not correctly checking if(result<0)....  But run second time data is not inserted only updated .....